# Text in div being bumped down - how to center?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of CSS-styled boxes.  Each box has a heading, followed by a number in a paragraph tag. Some of the headings are 2 lines, and in this case, the number shows up right where I want it: centered in the bottom part of the box. Where the heading is only 1 line, the number floats up higher than I'd like.  How can I get the number to be in the center of the white space?  What's going on here?

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/snp3gvke/

```
<div class="sm red left-margin"><h2>Website<br/>Visitors</h2><p>120,363</p>    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vertical-align:middle;` and `line-height`

Answer (score 0):

```
p   {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the hacky solution, but you can solve your problem by adding two line breaks to your headings. That's essentially the problem - when your heading only takes one line, it doesn't push the number down as far into the white part of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by using flexbox. I had to make some changes to your CSS to override the colors coming from `langsdale-dashboard.css` file.

I went ahead and made your CSS a little bit more efficient also. I made changes only on the CSS to make things work. Here's what I did:

1. Applied the colors to the `h2` instead of the parent container.
2. Removed the height from the parent containers and set the heights to the `h2` and `p` instead.
3. Applied `display:flex;` `justify-content:center;` and `align-items:center` to both the `h2` and the `p`.

I'm including the code below. You can also view it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/snp3gvke/11/

Let me know if you have any questions.

```css
.lg,.med,.sm {
 border-radius: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 position: relative;
}
.lg {
 width: 700px;
}
.med {
 width: 500px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.sm {
 width: 175px;
 display: inline-block 
}
.sm, .med, .lg {
 vertical-align: top;
}
.left-margin {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.row {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h2,
p {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h2 {
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
}
p   {
  height: 100px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.blue, .red, .green, .orange {
  background: transparent;
}
.blue {
 border-color: #41B6E6;
}
.blue h2 {
 background: #41B6E6;
}
.red {
 border-color: #ce2029;
}
.red h2 {
 background: #ce2029;
}
.green  {
 border-color: #C4D600;
}
.green h2  {
 background: #C4D600;
}
.orange {
 border-color: #E35205;
}
.orange h2 {
 background: #E35205;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://langsdale.ubalt.edu/zz-test/langsdale-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="lg blue">
            <h2>Walk-in Visitors</h2>
            <p>109,328</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="med red">
            <h2>Special Collections<br/>Flickr Views</h2>
            <p>75,985</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sm green left-margin">
            <h2>Questions<br/>Answered</h2>
            <p>19,570</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sm blue">
            <h2>Materials<br/>Circulated</h2>
            <p>375,985</p>
        </div>
        <div class="med orange left-margin">
            <h2>Instruction Session<br/>Attendees</h2>
            <p>2,045</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="med green">
            <h2>Database Searches</h2>
            <p>330,479</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sm red left-margin">
            <h2>Website<br/>Visitors</h2>
            <p>120,363</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="lg orange">
            <h2>Titles Borrowed via ILL</h2>
            <p>5,773</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for your detailed and thoughtful answer.  I do have a few questions:

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for your detailed and thoughtful answer.  I do have a few questions: -What, exactly, is margin:0 doing?  -border-radius is set on .lg .med & .sm, but you also set border-radius on h2.  Why?  -I don't understand what background:transparent is doing.  I get that its responsible for the white background behind the paragraph text, but I don't understand how the h2 can have color when you applied background transparent to .blue, .red, .green, and .orange?  Thanks again for taking the time to weigh in.  I am learning a lot from your response, although I miss my background gradient :-P

Comment: Also, border-color works in your Fiddle, but I'm seeing a black border in FireFox, Chrome, and IE.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Beren there is a margin being applied to both elements, it most likely be coming from your external css `langsdale-dashboard.css`. I had to override those margins by using `margin:0` to normalize them. The same also goes for the `background:transparent`. There are colors being applied to .red, .blue, .green, and .orange from your external css. So I had to override that by getting rid of that background. As for the `border-radius` if that's not set then the rounded corner on the h2 will not appear. I also updated the code to fix the border issue that you're seeing on other browsers.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused as to how the external css, langsdale-dashboard.css, could possibly apply if the html isn't calling this file?  Its not getting called in your JSFiddle, so why do you have to override styles from this external sheet?  Also, what on earth did you update to fix the cross-browser border issue?

Comment: @Beren It is calling the file in your fiddle `<link href="https://langsdale.ubalt.edu/zz-test/langsdale-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`.

Comment: @Beren It is also being called in my fiddle, if you look at the external resource on the left side bar.